# JWPlayer : issue in stop and play using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using [jwplayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/) to play videos on my site. I want to implement this scenario :

- A small thumb nail image represent the video.
- when a user click on the thumb image the jwplayer div shows and starts to play and the thumb image will hide .
- An external close button will allow to close the video. Then the thumb image will show again.

I am trying to accomplish it by using js.
The following is used to play the video:

```
   jwplayer('container').play();
```

and this is used to stop the jwplayer:

```
   jwplayer('container').stop();
```

The functions are working in chrome . But in **firefox** when I try to play the video in second time the jwplayer is in BUFFERING state. Also revert back to the placeholder image.

also shows an error sometime in console

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'toString'

This is a sample jsfiddle demo

> http://jsfiddle.net/35bGW/

Please help me to find a solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"_

Comment: try to add  primary:'flash' to jwplayer setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube now defaults to HTML5 mode as primary in 6.9.

There are some issues with setting up the player again with YouTube in HTML5 mode.

I have reported this as an issue to the player team here.

A work around, for now, is in your code, under this line:

```
stretching: 'exactfit',
```

Add:

```
primary: 'flash',
```

This should work around the issue for the time being.

Comment: Now it showing an Error: Ad adLoadError error: No ads were found in the ad response. At least one ad is required to be able to load or play. errorCode: 1001 in console

Comment: Also the mouse becomes hidden when hove over to the right of the player

Comment: That error message means that your ad tag is not serving any ads. It is unrelated to the Youtube issues you were having.

Comment: Finally I got a temporary solution for this problem. It seems to occur when my embed is initially hidden. So I have managed it with changing z-index of the embed container.

Comment: Ah, ok, got it, glad you got it.